# Error: table Tickers has 5 columns but 2 values were supplied - how add nulls

Tags: sql, insert

Hi I have such as code but, Japanese_stocks have 2 columns - and Tickers 5 how to add null or some certain values in the rest

```
INSERT INTO Tickers
SELECT * FROM Japanese_stocks
```

`table Tickers has 5 columns but 2 values were supplied`

Comment: We need to know the schema for `Tickets` and `Japanese_Stocks`. You probably should split `Tickets` into an additional table.

Comment: Don’t use *, explicitly list the columns and the default values you want to use where there isn’t a source column for the target column

Answer (score 0):

Thanks NickW

so how it should be:

```
INSERT INTO Table_name (Column1, Column2)
SELECT * FROM Table2_name
```